# EBean/Hibernate OneToMany only loading one way

Tags: hibernate, orm, playframework, ebean

I have a problem with my ORM mappings using Avaje Ebean where only the many relationship loads and not the one.

I have the following structure, an abstract class **Notification** using single table inheritance with implementing classes one of which is **ReportNotification**. 
Its a Report class with many notifications. 
When I run the code my Report returns all its notifications but my Notifications never loads the Report. The database looks correct and the values are correct in the table so I am not sure what I am doing wrong. 
I have tried many variations with no success.

In the database on the Notification table the foreign key reference id is named **report_report_id** for some reason but it was generated that way by Ebean.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "notification_type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Notification extends Model {
  @Id
  @Column(unique = true)
  public Long id;
```

Then I have two implementing classes but I will list only one for clarity.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorValue("REPORT")
public class ReportNotification extends Notification {

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="report_report_id", referencedColumnName = "report_report_id")
public Report report;
```

I have the report class it joins to

```
@Entity
public class Report extends Model {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
     @Column(name = "report_id")
     public Long reportId;

     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "report", targetEntity = ReportNotification.class)
     public Set<ReportNotification> notifications;
}
```

Comment: You don't state the actual code/query you execute.